# ActiveMQ STOMP heartbeat

Tags: websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

I am trying to set heartbeat to be 60000,60000 but when i do so i receive the first PONG (server to client) directly after it connect then wait till second interval to receive the second PONG after that it works perfectly

```
>>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:60000,60000


<<< PONG      // Received directly after 0 second
<<< CONNECTED
server:ActiveMQ/5.13.2
heart-beat:60000,60000
session:ID:xxxxxxxxx-42585-1460378487077-3:8
version:1.1
user-name:009613050252


connected to server ActiveMQ/5.13.2
send PING every 60000ms
check PONG every 60000ms
Connected: CONNECTED
user-name:009613050252
version:1.1
session:ID:xxxxxxxxxxxx-42585-1460378487077-3:8
heart-beat:60000,60000
server:ActiveMQ/5.13.2


stomp.min.js:8 >>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/user/queue/call


stomp.min.js:8 >>> PING        //Sent at 60 second but nothing is received from server
stomp.min.js:8 <<< PONG        //Received at 120 second
stomp.min.js:8 >>> PING        //Sent at 120 second
stomp.min.js:8 >>> DISCONNECT
```

if i did not set any value and kept the default it worked perfectly but if i set manualy the default value of 10 second it behave same as before

Comment: Maybe this old bug cause Your problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4710